# Change whole theme depending on resolution

Tags: themes

Is it possible to change whole theme depending on resolution?
I have different theme for mobile users. I need to change theme to mobile when user has for example smaller than 600px resolution.

Theme switcher based on device data is not solution (mobile switcher etc.).

Comment: There is no wordpress way to change themes based on screen resolution.

Comment: There is no way to detect screen resolution server-side. If device data is not the solution for you neither a responsive desing, I'm not sure if you will can to do what you want. You could detect de resolution with javascript and send back to the server in a ajax request and send back the theme you want but that is quite crazy and you still need to send a response from the server before you know the screen resolution and, of course, won't work for non-javascript users.

Comment: Have a look at my answer to a similar type of question [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/156494/31545)